# SQL Query to get results from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one called files_downloads, and the other called quiz_attempts, both share column = `uname`

I am trying to get two main results, (with two scripts) 
1) Users who downloaded files and did the quizzes
2) Users who didn't download (Show NA) files and DID quizzes.
Here is code of my tries:

```
SELECT f.fname, f.uname, q.qname, q.first, q.second, q.third, q.fourth,q.fifth
FROM files_downloaded f
JOIN quiz_attempts q ON q.uname = f.uname
WHERE f.fname LIKE  '%gol14_%'
AND q.qname LIKE  '%onlinelernen%'
ORDER BY  `f`.`uname` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I spent over 5 hours to get this solved, and i cannot. i feel crazy about it!

`fname                 uname qname              first second third fourth fifth
gol14_02_1_einheit.pdf 11mg onlinelernen_quiz_1 100    0    0    0    0`

Comment: What's q.first, q.second, q.third, etc..? What if a user downloaded a file and did 2 quizes? Would there need to be two lines in your output? What if a user did 10 downloads and no quizes, do you care about them? What if a user downloaded 10 files and did 5 quizes, would you want 50 records in your output?

Comment: look into joining ON uname. ON is a keyword. Should get you results you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users who downloaded files and did the quizzes:

```
SELECT f.uname FROM files_downloaded f JOIN quiz_attempts q ON(q.uname = f.uname);
```

Users who didn't download files and did quizzes:

```
SELECT q.uname FROM files_downloaded f RIGHT JOIN quiz_attempts q ON(q.uname = f.uname) WHERE f.fname IS NULL;
```

P.S.: Not showing "NA", only selecting the users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to be your final query, but it answers your exact question, but with a single SQL query:

> I am trying to get two main results, (with two scripts) 1) Users who downloaded files and did the quizzes 2) Users who didn't download (Show NA) files and DID quizzes.

Using a CASE statement to figure out who downloaded a file and did a quiz versus who just did a quiz, and two subqueries to get counts of quizzes taken and count of files downloaded per user, using the same restrictions you have in your WHERE statement above.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN quizcount > 0
            AND dlcount > 0
            THEN "did both"
        WHEN quizcount > 0
            AND dlcount = 0
            THEN "only did quizzes"
        END AS `ActionType`,
    q.uname,
    q.quizcount,
    f.dlcount
FROM (
    SELECT uname,
        count(*) AS quizcount
    FROM quiz_attempts
    WHERE qname LIKE '%onlinelernen%'
    GROUP BY uname
    ) AS q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT uname,
        count(*) AS dlcount
    FROM files_downloaded
    WHERE fname LIKE '%gol14_%'
    GROUP BY uname
    ) AS f
    ON q.uname = f.uname
ORDER BY q.uname
```